# I'm trying to get the image srouce of an ImageView

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm doing a card matching game at the moment and I am fairly new to Android studio so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm at the point where i am trying to compare two image views to see if they have the same image source.

While i'm able to do this to set the image source

```
ImageView obImg = findViewById(R.id.ivCard2);
obImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.AceS);
```

After searching around for a while i'm not sure how to get that image resource

```
//there's nothing simple like
obImg.getImageResource;

//and this seems to crash my program
obImg.getTag();
```

Thanks for everyone's help in advance

Comment: You may want to rethink this. Rather than trying to get the image source from an Image View you should instead have an underlying structure (Array/List etc) that contains the cards along with their associated ID's, and that array/list is what determines which image is shown, and that array is what should be checked to get an ID when comparing cards. Note that getTag() is not a valid method call, see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView

Comment: `while i'm not sure how to get that image resource` Do you mean `while i'm not sure how to get that image resource id`?